# Не работает javascript на dle 9.3

Tags: javascript

В общем сегодня днем мой сайт взломали (запустили троян на сайт), после чего почти все файлы движка были удалены. Когда разобрался, что к чему, заново закачал все файлы на сервер, сайт снова заработал, но перестали полностью работать javascripts, кто может подсказать, в чем дело и как решить эту проблему?

Ссылка на сайт: [cайт](http://proscripts.ru/).

Answer (score 1):

> `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) **jqueryui.js**
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) **jquery.js**
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) **highslide.js**
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) **jquery.jmpopups-0.5.1.js:12**
> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined /dle/:24
> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined /dle/:81
> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined /dle/:86
> Uncaught ReferenceError: hs is not defined ddaccordion.js:241
> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined ddaccordion.js:143
> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Ваши скрипты тупо не загружаются в браузер. Проверьте права доступа на папки и наличие этих файлов...

Answer (score 0):

У вас путь к ним неправильно прописан скорее всего: чтобы они работали, они должны быть доступны для браузера пользователя. А у меня, например, http://proscripts.ru/engine/classes/js/dle_js.js не открывается.

Answer (score 0):

"Указанный в ссылке скрипт не загружен" - скрипты утеряны. проверьте их на наличие. Перезалейте их :)

http://proscripts.ru/engine/classes/js/jquery.js - его просто нет на месте...

Да - и совет. После троянов удаляйте ВСЕ файлы (прям рекурсивно всю папку) и перезаливайте заново все с нуля. Трояны имеют обыкновение оставлять всякие хвосты - всякие файлики служебные (**.htaccess** например).